# Why am I only getting one association with this model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, relational-database, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize for Node.js I have defined some relationships. The only issue is that the `promotion` models contain just one `gamePlayLog` each instead of all for each. The example promotion below should have over 100 `gamePlayLogs`'s. I copied just one from the array of returned promotions/tournaments for reference. Am I doing something wrong?

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    seqlz = new Sequelize('wegweg', 'wegwegweg', 'wegwegweg!', {
        host: '...',
        port: '3306',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        timezone: 'UTC-05:00',
        pool: {
            max: 5,
            min: 0,
            idle: 10000
        }
    }),
    Promotion = seqlz.define('promotion', {
        tournamentId: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        iconFilePath: Sequelize.STRING,
        name: Sequelize.STRING(75),
        eventStartDate: Sequelize.DATE,
        eventEndDate: Sequelize.DATE
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'Tournament'
    }),
    Advertiser = seqlz.define('advertiser', {
        advertiserId: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: Sequelize.STRING(75),
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'Advertiser'
    }),
    Game = seqlz.define('game', {
        gameId: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: Sequelize.STRING(75)
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'Game'
    }),
    GamePlayLog = seqlz.define('gamePlayLog', {
        gamePlayLogId: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        createdDate: Sequelize.DATE
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        tableName: 'GamePlayLog'
    });

Promotion.belongsTo(Advertiser, {foreignKey: 'advertiserId'});
Promotion.belongsTo(Game, {foreignKey: 'gameId'});
Promotion.hasMany(GamePlayLog, {foreignKey: 'gamePlayLogId'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    Promotion.findAll({
        where: {status: 3},
        include: [Advertiser, Game, GamePlayLog]
    }).then(function(promos) {
        context.done(null, promos);
    });
};



{
    "tournamentId": 607,
    "iconFilePath": "uploadfiles/tournament/icon/...-mobile-icon.jpg",
    "name": "Win Custom Artwork",
    "eventStartDate": "2015-07-27T05:00:00.000Z",
    "eventEndDate": "2016-08-02T04:00:00.000Z",
    "advertiserId": 37,
    "gameId": 14,
    "advertiser": {
      "advertiserId": 37,
      "name": "...Customs"
    },
    "game": {
      "gameId": 14,
      "name": "Eggcetera"
    },
    "gamePlayLogs": [
      {
        "gamePlayLogId": 607,
        "createdDate": "2015-02-26T13:31:34.000Z"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the foreign key as the `gamePlayerLogId` but that's a primary key in the `gamePlayerLog` table so there will only ever be one with a corresponding id.  I think what you probably want is to specify the promotion id in the `gamePlayerLog` table as the foreign key.

Comment: How dumb of me, it should be `tournamentId` which is `Promo`'s primary key. Thanks for catching that!